# .htaccess incorrectly http redirects to http://www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, no-www

I am trying to redirect all requests to https non www subdomain, like this:

```
http://sub.example.com -> https://sub.example.com

http://www.sub.example.com -> https://sub.example.com

https://www.sub.example.com -> https://sub.example.com
```

Using this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

But what happens is that if I visit

```
http://sub.example.com
```

it gets redirected to

```
https://www.sub.example.com
```

which I don't understand. There are no other lines in the `.htaccess` file. I have read and tried many other questions at SO and can not have it done.

Comment: This is not happening in your current rule. Have you tried testing in a new browser to avoid old cache?

Comment: Is there anything in your application logic that would trigger a redirect? I concur with anubhava - there's nothing in the code you have posted that would result in such a redirect.

Comment: there is not (it is angular app, but no redirection). neither is there .htaccess in parent directory

Answer (score -1):

Check out this question at DigitalOcean, the first answer seems to match what you are looking for it seems like the solution is to replace the RewriteCond in the vhost conf file from this (within the `<VirtualHost *:443>` section):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
```

To this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
```

As described in screenpilot’s answer available [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-permanently-redirect-www-subdomain-to-subdomain-when-using-wildcard-ssl).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks I tried to edit my answer could you please review It again?

Comment: Please pay attention to the quotes you use: `”` != `"`

Comment: Ok I will keep that in mind, but these are my default ones in iOS

Comment: It did not unfortunately work. I have sorted it out by creating www folder in sub.domain.com and placing separate htaccess file redirecting to https://sub.domain.com. I will keep looking for better solution though